# how to calculate total value for the below JSON value U.O.M Wise in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, data-structures

how to calculate total value for the below JSON value U.O.M Wise in Java?

sequence can be vary. We cannot expect number of uoms and sequence of results.

i have created hashset and made unique uom.

```
{
    value=100
    uom=kg
},
{
    value=200
    uom=kg
},
{
    value=100
    uom=lt
},
{
    value=100
    uom=ab
},
{
    value=100
    uom=lt
}
```

Please provide some code ref

Comment: That isn't valid json.

Comment: I've manually typed here.

Comment: Ok.  In any case, a lot of this depends on code you already have.  Do you use Gson, do you use Jackson, do you manually parse the Json?  What do you mean with 'created unique uom'?  Have you got an interface which represents this and lets you transform between different values, etc.?

Comment: @KIRITHIGAN If I am Right, Do you want to calculate the sum of kg, lt , etc ?

Answer (score 1):

1. This is not valid JSON as it uses = as key\value separator (change to something like this and use tools like JSONLint to validate):

   ```
   [{
           "value": "100",
           "uom": "kg"
       }, {
           "value": "200",
           "uom": "kg"
       }, {
           "value": "100",
           "uom": "lt"
       }, {
           "value": "100",
           "uom": "ab"
       }, {
           "value": "100",
           "uom": "lt"
       }
   ]
   ```
2. Even having this structure you can parse it into a collection of touples (value, uom) and then just sum everything having same uom
   For example you can use this:

   ```
   javax.json.JsonArray body = Json.createReader(new StringReader(YOUR_JSON_STRING)).readArray();
   ```

   and read a JSON to array of touples